# Getting rid of duplicates based on older date in mysql

Tags: mysql

Picture this... a person adds a row of data about a computer into mysql and he again adds another row of essentially same row of data except that the date is different where each date is always stamped with the insert.

I want to be able to eliminate duplicates and show only the most recent row.

Let's say we have a "computers" table with 3 fields: ID, COMPUTER, DATEADD

inside the table goes like this

```
1, dell, 2010-10-09
2, dell, 2011-10-10
3, gateway, 2010-03-03
4, dell, 2010-02-02
```

simple, ok... how do I get rid of dups of dell and only get dell with the latest date?

I tried this query:

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM  `computers` 
  GROUP BY computer
  ORDER BY dates ASC
```

it doesnt perform as I expect - the date is not the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DESC` instead of `ASC`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `computers` 
GROUP BY computer
ORDER BY dateadd DESC;
```

**UPDATE 1**

Another shot:

```
SELECT *
  FROM computers c
 WHERE dateadd = (SELECT MAX(dateadd) 
                    FROM computers 
                   WHERE computer = c.computer)
```

but some problems might arise, if you have two or more entries of the same computer for one date.

Comment: Try to add an INDEX on the dateadd column.  This might speed up the query.

Comment: Explain why that query works as expected.. it doesn't seem intuitive to me... no GROUP BY or DINSTINCT... how does it eliminate dups?

Comment: MySQL would first filter the data based on the WHERE clause, after that it performs the search for the maximum date value.  Since you want the maximum date for a given group of computers, then we could simply omit the GROUP BY c.computer, since it doesn't actually do anything in our situation (WHERE clause limited the results to one computer type).

Comment: Thanks Greg for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Revised per comment

```
SELECT * FROM
computers
INNER JOIN
(SELECT computer, MAX(dates) as dates
FROM computers
GROUP BY computer) AS max_dates ON computers.computer = max_dates.computer AND computers.dates = max_dates.dates
```

Or you could change your table structure to have a unique index on computer field, and then just do all your data inserts as `REPLACE INTO` queries so you never have duplicates, if you don't care about having a history of entries.

Comment: no, it's not what i wanted. I tried that but it only tells you the latest date of each group, but I want the whole row displayed with the latest date. With that query, it still shows the earliest date even though the max(date) is shown next showing the latest date.

Comment: OK didn't know the id held any value to you.  Please see revised answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to alias the aggregated field.  See the revised query in the answer.